# Eliminating non-distinct permutations

Tags: java, permutation

Was wondering how to disregard repeated permutations when considering strings within longer strings. As of right now, I've managed to create a program that takes a string, subject it to different permutations, and count how many are present within a longer string, however in regards to finding distinct, I've been utterly stuck; any advice would be much appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {
static final int MAX = 200000; 
public static int numbo;
public static void main (String args[]) {
  new main ();
}

public main () {

String txt = "abacabaa"; 
String pat = "aab";

search(pat, txt); 

System.out.println(numbo);
} 

static boolean compare(char arr1[], char arr2[]) { 
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
  if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true; 
} 

static void search(String pat, String txt) { 
int M = pat.length(); 
int N = txt.length(); 


char[] countP = new char[MAX]; 
char[] countTW = new char[MAX];
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
  (countP[pat.charAt(i)])++; 
  (countTW[txt.charAt(i)])++; 
} 

//Goes through remaining characters of pattern
for (int i = M; i < N; i++) { 

  //Compares counts of current window of text with counts of pattern[]
  if (compare(countP, countTW)) {
    System.out.println("Found at Index " + (i - M)); 
    numbo++;
  }

  //Adds current character to current window 
  (countTW[txt.charAt(i)])++; 

  //Removes the first character of previous window 
  countTW[txt.charAt(i-M)]--; 
}

if (compare(countP, countTW)) {
  numbo++;
  System.out.println("Found at Index " + (N - M)); 
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do? Find the number of sections within string `txt`, which are one of all the permutations of the characters of string `pat`? What does *distinct* mean in this context?

Comment: Yep, pretty much. What you mentioned did occur to me, but I still ended up including the repetitions of permutations that were the same; which is pretty much the same problem either way. Sorry about that!

Comment: Pardon? I don't believe I follow.

Comment: Calculate all permutations upfront and put them in a list L. Remember the lenght of L (int lenL = L.length;). Then you slide your window over txt, if the section in focus matches one of the elements in L, you remove it from L. repeat until you're at the end of txt or L is empty. The result is lenL - L.length. If I got you right.